# Error while authenticating access to a resource through Azure AD oauth

Tags: azure, ms-office, exchange-server, office365, azure-active-directory

I'm using Oauth provided by Azure AD to authorize the following resources;

https://mySite-my.sharepoint.com (my sharepoint site) >>> For Sharepoint/OneDrive

https://outlook.office365.com >>> For Mail, Calendar(Exchange)

https://graph.windows.net >>> For Graph API

I have given all the rights to my APP from Azure Portal and it even prompts that it is going to access such and such during the Oauth process.

But when I try to authorize the following resource (send 'refresh_token' with the following in the 'resource' field)

**Resource**

https://reports.office365.com/ >>> Resource for Reports (Audit) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj984342(v=office.15).aspx

I get the following error;

**Message**

```
{"error":"invalid_resource","error_description":"AADSTS50001: Resource 'https://reports.office365.com/' is not registered for the account.\r\nTrace ID: 609fb376-d2fc-49ee-85e8-8addcd5c4592\r\nCorrelation ID: c1057eae-70d1-425e-8d87-d08ad90ea050\r\nTimestamp: 2014-08-24 16:27:58Z","error_codes":[50001],"timestamp":"2014-08-24 16:27:58Z","trace_id":"609fb376-d2fc-49ee-85e8-8addcd5c4592","correlation_id":"c1057eae-70d1-425e-8d87-d08ad90ea050"}
```

What am I doing wrong? By the looks of it, it is suggesting that there is some configuration that I need to do before I try doing what I had been doing!

For references I am pasting some of the URLs that I've been following to achieve this goal;

Auth >>>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx

APIs(resources) >>>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380(v=office.15).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841%28v=office.15%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15).aspx

Much appreciated!

Comment: I am having the same issue for the Graph resource. Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: Nope, but it is sure due on me to redo this activity (if I can find something now that I couldn't back then)